# how to detect if '\n' is present in python list?

Tags: python

I have a list consist of some items. one of the items is \n. I want to check if my list contains '\n.' at the end by using if condition but it is not working...

```py
content = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', '\n.']
if content[-1] == ('\n.' or '\\n.')
   print('it works')
else:
   print('it does not')
```

Comment: `if content[-1] == '\n.' or content[-1] == '\\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```py
content = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', '\n.']
if '\n.' in content or '\\n.' in content: print('It works')
else: print('It does not')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. This code can identify the `\n.` and `\\n.` in your list and furthermore it can check if them are the last elements in your list.

**Code:**

```
content = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "\n."]
if "\n." in content:
    print(r"\n in list")
    if "\n." == content[-1]:
        print(r"\n is the last element in list")
    else:
        print(r"\n is not the last element in list")
elif "\\n." in content:
    print(r"\\n in list")
    if "\\n." == content[-1]:
        print(r"\\n is the last element in list")
    else:
        print(r"\\n is not the last element in list")
else:
    print(r"\n or \\n are not in list")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
\n in list
\n is the last element in list
```

---

If your `content` list is:

```
content = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "\n.", "asdf"]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
\n in list
\n is not the last element in list
```

---

If your `content` list is:

```
content = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "\\n."]
```

**Otuput:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
\\n in list
\\n is the last element in list
```

---

If your `content` list is:

```
content = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "\\n.", "asdf"]
```

**Otuput:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
\\n in list
\\n is not the last element in list
```

---

If your `content` list is:

```
content = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "asdf"]
```

**Otuput:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
\n or \\n are not in list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', '\n.']
if content[-1] == ('\n.' or '\\n.'):
   print('it works')
else:
   print('it does not')
```

Colon is missing in your code